# after updating to kitkat, my glass app that inserts cards in the time line stopped working

Tags: android, google-glass

The app I am developing for API 15 stopped working after the glass update to KitKat.

I am having the following error:

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager*

on the following line :

```
mTimelineManager = TimelineManager.from(this);
```

I also tested with the Glass Demos and same thing happens.
Has anybody been able to solve this?

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest version of the gdk?

Comment: ok, yesterday i verified a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the release notes https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes

> **Changes to TimelineManager:**
>
> The TimelineManager class and support for static cards from the GDK have been removed.